# Ajax login box doesn't call PHP file to continue process

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The Ajax function for logging in and validating doesn't seem to get to the .php file for validation.

I'm new to both JS and Ajax and followed a few online tutorials, I then tried to implement this with what I had in place already and the problems started.

I've put an echo at the top of the page that Ajax calls, it never gets displayed. I've typed into url to be sure and it works fine. (displays the echo)

I've gone over the code a few times and can't see any obvious errors but then I'm not entirely certain of what I should be looking for.

If I leave the PHP in the 'header' of the HTML page it works fine but I understand this is bad practice.  Grateful for any help.

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" action="" id="ourLoginFormID_JS">
                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username"  name="username" autocomplete="off" class="required" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['username']); ?>"  />
                    </div>

                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="required"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label> &nbsp; </label>
                        <input type="submit" name="loginButton" id="loginButton" value="Login!" onclick="validLogin()"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="statusLogin"></div>
                </form>
```

The Ajax:

```
function validLogin(){

$('.error').hide();
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username == ""){
    $('label#usernameError').show();
    $('input#username').focus();
    return false;
}

$('.error').hide();
var password = $('#password').val();
if(password == ""){
    $('label#passwordError').show();
    $('input#password').focus();
    return false;
}

var params = "username="+username+"&password="+password;
var url = "loginProcessAjax.php";

$("#statusLogin").show();
$("#statusLogin").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" />');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: params,

    beforeSend: function() {
        document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= 'checking...'  ;
    },

    complete: function() {

    },

    success: function(html) {
        $("#statusLogin").hide();
        document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= html;
        if(html=="success"){

            window.location = "index.php"

        }

    }
});
}
```

PHP - I understand there may be some conflicting issues on this page but it doesn't get that far, however if you've any pointers that'd also be fantastic.

```
<?php
//check fields are filled in
echo "HULLOOOO!!!!!"; // doesn't display when run in function but ok from url

if(empty($_POST) === false){

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

//validate fields
if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true){
    $errors[] = 'Your username and password are needed.';
}else if($users->userExists($username) === false){
    $errors[] = 'That username does not exist';
}else if($users->emailActivated($username) === false){
    $errors[] = 'You need to activate the account, please check your email.';
}else{

    //start login
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if($login === false){
        $errors[] = 'That username or password is invalid';
//
//            if(empty($errors) === false){
//                echo '<p>' .implode('</p><p>', $errors).'</p>';
//            }

    }else{
        //destroy old session and create new - prevents session fixation attacks
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        //all details are correct - the method returns the id to be sotred as a session
        $_SESSION['id'] = $login;
        //send user to their home page
        echo "success";
        header('Location: userHome.php');
        exit();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are using ajax for no good reason at all! The point is to update the page without reloading, not to do an ajax call, and immediately redirect, then you might as well just use the regular form submit ?

Comment: You refer to the window.location = "index.php"?  When it's working I'd like it to stay on the same page

Comment: Try and `alert(html)` in the `success function` & add a `error: function(e){alert(e)}`

Comment: The main reason for using is because I wanted a login without refresh, someone suggested ajax, and here I am.

Comment: @Connor, I'm assuming that it reaches the succeed as the remainder executes, the 'statusLogin' hides.

Comment: Try [***this code***](http://jsfiddle.net/66MdF/1/) and see what happens ?

Comment: And why are you redirecting in the PHP file after you've returned `'success'`, you should just exit there, not redirect ?

Comment: @adeneo, it doesn't reach the PHP but yes the redirect will need to go, I tried the code in your fiddle and it failed

Comment: With an alert telling you it failed! If so check the console to see the error message.

Comment: @adeneo, I did check, it says 'error' and then tells me the line within the function that prompted it - the console.log(b).  Nothing else.

Comment: Inside the fail function add console logs for `a` and `c` as well, and see what you get? The console isn't showing a `GET - 404` line when the ajax call tries to get the PHP file or anything like that ?

Comment: @adeneo, no, the console isn't showing anything at all.  The alert box says object Object but nothign else

Comment: In my code there is only one alert, and it's alerting a string, not an object, so how it can alert "Object Object" is beyond me ?

Comment: @adeneo, added b and c.  a returns Object, b returns error

Comment: I put the PHP code back into the header of where the HTML is.  Ajax still fails but login is successful.  -.-

Comment: It just says "Object" in the console? What browser are you using!

Comment: @adeneo chrome and safari.

Comment: in chrome I get no errors at all

Answer (score 0):

Your data to the post request is not formatted in the right way. Use `{'property1': 'value1', etc}`.

First try to display the data with PHP, make it more complex when you're sure the connection between jQuery and PHP is working well.

Use Firebug or developer tools to see if there errors occur.

Comment: When only using PHP it works fine.  The jQuery doesn't seem to be calling the php though

Comment: Oke, that's good to know. You should check the way of sending parameters to the .php script. It should be formatted like I said in my answer.

Comment: You can use the data in your script as $_REQUEST['property1'] by the way.

Comment: Why would `$_REQUEST` make any difference?

Comment: He's using $_POST, but you can also use $_GET. In this case it doesn't matter indeed.